# To find the image of a strip under a given mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

**Question** : Find the image of the strip $0<\operatorname{Im} z<1$ under the mapping $w=(z-i) / z$ ?

**My Approach** : Writing $z=x+iy$, the given mapping is
$$w = u + i v =  \frac{x^2+y(y-1)- i x}{x^2 + y^2}$$

When $y=0$, $w=1-i/x$ and when $y=1$, $w=x^2-ix/x^2+1$. Writing $w=u+iv$ and trying to get an expression in terms of $u$ and $v$, I wasn't successful. Any help in solving this question is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: try a more geometric approach. $(z - i)/z$ defines a linear fractional transformation on the complex numbers. Such things map straight lines in the complex planes to lines or circles. The image of a straight line is determined by its values on three distinct points on the line. Try to see what the transformation does to the edges of your strip.

Comment: @RobArthan, thank you for the suggestion ! Can you please elaborate it. We know that under a Mobius Transformation, a straight line passing through the origin (here Im z = 0) maps to a straight line and a $\text{Im} z= 1$ maps to a circle.

Comment: I have elaborated the comment into an answer. Please check it carefully as I could easily have got some of the numerical details wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear fractional transformation (a.k.a., Möbius transformation) maps straight lines in the complex plane to lines or circles and maps the half-planes separated by a straight line to half-planes or to the interior or exterior of a circle as appropriate. You only need to look at three distinct values of the transformation on three points on a line to tell whether or not you have a line or a circle and then looking at the value on one point off the line will tell where the half-planes separated by the line are mapped. To understand this geometrically, it is very helpful to think of the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), the result of adding a point at infinity to the complex plane, which lets us think of straight lines in the planes as circles that pass through $\infty$ and lets us write $u/0 =\infty$, provided $u \neq 0$..

So let's look at the edges $\operatorname{Im}z = 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}z = 1$ of the strip.

$\mathbf{\operatorname{Im}z = 0{:}}$

We have $w(0) = \infty$, so the image of this edge of the strip is a straight line. We have $w(1) = 1 - i$ and $w(2) = 1 - i/2$. So the image of this edge is the vertical line $\operatorname{Re}z = 1$. Also $w(i) = 0$, so $w$ maps the half-plane above this edge to the half-plane to the left of this vertical line.

$\mathbf{\operatorname{Im}z = 1{:}}$

We have $w(i) = 0$, $w(1 + i) = 1/2 - i/2$ and $w(-1 + i) = 1/2 + i/2$. These three values are not collinear, so the image of the line is a circle, which we can see must be the circle of radius $1/2$ centred at $1/2$. Also $w(2i) = 1/2$ so $w$ maps the half-plane above this edge to the interior of the circle, and hence maps the half-plane below this edge to the exterior of the circle.

**Conclusion:**

The image of the strip is the intersection of the open half-plane to the left of the line $\operatorname{Re}z = 1$ with the exterior of the circle $|z - 1/2| = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive solution.

Comment: My pleasure: it helped sober me up after a departmental Christmas party!